# How to correctly link to multiple varying SQL tables using c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have multiple SQL database tables whose names all begin with "access_".

Each table contains an "id_employees" column, and then a number of bit columns to define access to certain areas of different apps. There are a varying number of bit columns in each table, each with different names, and new tables will be added as new sections are developed.

I am using Kendo and MVC, and what I would like to do is have one view with a dropdown of all tables, and load a partial view underneath with a grid of the bits from the selected table. These would both be dynamically generated from the database, meaning we'd only have to add another table to the database, without having to modify the controlling program too.

I currently have a stored procedure which returns all access_ tables, and the columns in each. These are then put into classes similar to:

```
Public Class access_parent
{
    public access_parent()
    {
        AccessParams = new List<access_params>();
    }

    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<access_params> AccessParams { get; set; }
}

Public Class access_params
{
    public string ParamName { get; set; }
    public string ParamValue { get; set; }
    public virtual access_parent AccessParent {get; set; }
}
```

but I'm not sure this is the correct approach. I should be able to handle the Kendo and MVC code, if I could just figure out the correct way to handle the situation, but to be honest I'm lost. Is there a way to do this or am I making work for myself by trying to be too clever and ending up dumb?

Comment: I think you are making work for yourself by having more database tables than you need.

Comment: I agree with @DanBracuk, Normalize it down to a single access table.

Comment: Ok thanks, I felt it was a bit too 'scattered'. The problem is it also doesn't feel right to have 20 apps accessing 5 different columns in an ever growing database table. Though that looks to be the way forward.